# Piece-wise square of vector, piece-wise product of two vectors in C++ Eigen

Tags: c++11, vector, eigen, square, piecewise

Granted that `v`, `a` are `Eigen::VectorXd` vectors with n dimensions, I would like to make the following piece-wise operations:

- The piece-wise multiplication of `v` by `a`, i.e., the vector `(a[1]*v[1], ..., a[n]*v[n])`, and
- The piece-wise square of `v`, i.e., the vector `(v[1]*v[1], ..., v[n]*v[n])`.

Does `Eigen` provide methods for the above operations, or do I need to implement them manually? There are certainly very simple, but I would like them to run as fast as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: [Avi's answer is definitely a better solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34374488/3935325)

Well, if you get the first one going, the second one is just a particular case where `a=v`.

The easiest way of doing the first operation is creating a diagonal matrix from `a` and doing a normal product.

Taking a look at the [docs](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__QuickRefPage.html#QuickRef_DiagTriSymm), you can use `a.asDiagonal()`.

About efficiency, perhaps this isn't what you want if you want it to be 'as fast as possible'. In that case, you should measure this against a loop and vector construction to see if there's any practical difference to you.

Comment: I see, thanks! I was trying to avoid matrix by vector multiplications, since I believe that this is going to be slower than vector by vector ones. But probably I need to implement both ways and measure execution times.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Eigen internals, but the docs mention that `asDiagonal` returns a `DiagonalWrapper` instead of a whole matrix or even a new diagonal matrix itself. So it is possible that it is quite efficient.

Comment: I'll try that, thanks again. What I want now is to get the diagonal part of a full matrix, which I could implement it myself, I think there is not a similar Eigen function.

Answer (score 8):

For dealing with element wise operations such as your question, Eigen provides the [`Array`](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1Array.html) class. So, to do the operations you asked about you would write the point-wise product as:

```
c = a.array() * v.array(); // Long version
c = a.cwiseProduct(v);     // Short(er) version
```

and for the square you have:

```
s = v.array().square();    // Probably what you want to use
s = v.array().abs2();      // Two operations: abs() then square()
s = v.cwiseAbs2();         // Same as above
```

Using a `VectorXd` as an array does not incur a copy, so it is quite efficient.